# Unable to Sign-Up and Create a Free IBM Cloud Account

Tags: user-accounts, cloud

I am here because IBM Cloud support is useless and hope somebody here may have better suggestions.

As stated in the title, I want to sign-up with IBM Cloud to try out Watson. I have already created an IBM ID. Here's what I am doing and the issue I face:

1. Go to https://cloud.ibm.com
2. Click on "`Create an IBM Cloud Account`".
3. Under the "**Create a free account**" section, it asks for an email ID.
4. When I used an @tuta.io email, I get the error *"Enter a valid email address"*.
5. Ok, maybe they only check for .com/.net/.org ... so I use another email ID that I used to create the IBM ID.
6. This time it accepts it and says: "*This email address is associated with an IBMid. You'll log in to your IBM Cloud account with this IBMid.*"
7. I click on "`Create Account`" button.
8. I get this error message: "***Failure during registration***
   Try again in a few minutes. If you continue having problems, contact us at this link: https://watson.service-now.com/wcp"
9. Clicking on the link take me to "**IBM Cloud Service Portal**".
10. There's a link at top-right - "**Login**" and a link at bottom-right "**Can't Log In?**".
11. I click on "Login" and it takes me to a page that says "**Log In to IBM**" and asks the user to enter their IBM Id.
12. When I enter my IBMId credentials, it loads a page that says "**We're sending you to our enhanced IBM Cloud Support Center.**" with a 10 second countdown for redirection.
13. It tries to load something called integrated cloud support or something and then redirects me back to the "**Create an Account**" page with the message: "*Let's get you started. You don't have an IBM Cloud account yet. Sign up for one with your IBMid to start building in the cloud.*"
14. So I repeat step 1 to step 7 again. Which again gives me the same error as step 8 (***Failure during registration*** Try again in a few minutes. If you continue having problems, contact us at this link: https://watson.service-now.com/wcp).
15. I again click the link and this time I am greeted with "**Welcome to the IBM Cloud Service Portal**" with links to "*contact support | view ticket history | IBM Cloud status*".
16. I click "`Contact Support`" and this loads a "**Create Case**" page with an error message in red: "*Your accounts are inactive and must be activated to open a case in this portal. If you received this message in error and have an active account, submit a case [here](https://watson.service-now.com/x_ibmwc_open_case_app).*"
17. So I click that link which loads a form with the title "**Create an Account, Login or Billing Request**".
18. Filling up this form and explaining the issue creates a support ticket with a corresponding case ID.
19. I also get an email that a case ticket has been created with a link to access it.
20. IBM posts updates to these tickets and asks me to check it out. Now here's the bummer - I can't access the case tickets either because it fails with the error message: "**Error 500: java.lang.NullPointerException**".

You can't reply to the support emails as IBM asks you to access and update the case ticket only through their support system. Since you don't take any actions, IBM closes the ticket after 7 days.

I have read online how their Bluemix system that they use for their cloud is a total mess with issues like mine.

Any suggestions to end my frustration welcome!

Comment: After spending over an hour trying to register for an IBM Cloud account, all I could get from their site was "Error: Your account cannot be created at this time.".  I had no problem signing up for an IBMid account.  That went smoothly.  But even using my IBMid account to try to create an IBM Cloud account failed.  Sigh.  So I tried creating a support ticket, but that required an IBM Cloud account... which I can't create.  Double sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had exactly the same issue as described. I can tell you what worked for me: I first tried to register using an email on yandex.ru and kept seeing the Failure page. Then I used a gmail.com email address and it worked fine immediately. So maybe you should try using a different email? Just a guess...

Comment: I avoid GYM (Google, Yahoo, Microsoft) services. If that's really the issue then it seems pretty shortsighted of IBM. And also makes it suspicious whether data sharing of users data for data mining is involved.

Comment: Had the same problem switched from my protonmail to my gmail adress and it worked